# How to use the <noscript> element "right"?

Tags: html, validation

The HTML validator I found today - http://html5.validator.nu/ - says that my use of the `<noscript>` element is wrong. My XHTML source code is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de">
<body>
<div id="head">
<noscript>
<p>JavaScript is disabled.</p>
</noscript>
...
```

The error message from the validator is this:

> Error: XHTML element noscript not allowed as child of XHTML element div in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)
>
> Contexts in which element noscript may be used:
>
> - In a head element of an HTML document, if there are no ancestor noscript elements.
> - Where phrasing content is expected in HTML documents, if there are no ancestor noscript elements.
>
> Content model for element div:
>
> - Flow content.

Now I went on to the Mozilla Documentation and tried to understand what that means. I have found some information about content categories, flow content, phrasing content, what elements belong to each category (whatever "belong" means exactly) and how the `<noscript>` element may be used. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/noscript)

I now know this: `<div>` must contain flow content. `<noscript>` must occur in phrasing content. That obviously doesn't match. How can I manage that? Many elements are in both, flow and phrasing, categories though. They don't seem to be disjunct sets, so some can't decide or I don't get it.

How does the HTML specification intend to solve this quirks?

Comment: I have added the doctype and html elements to clarify that my page is XHTML, if that helps in analysing it. I have not played with different doctypes yet. I'm using XHTML 1.1 for a while now, but I'm thinking about using HTML5 instead in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn’t use an HTML5 validator to validate your XHTML 1.1 document.

The HTML5 spec says about the [`noscript` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/scripting-1.html#the-noscript-element):

> The `noscript` element must not be used in XML documents.

So `noscript` inside `div` isn’t allowed in XHTML5, but it’s allowed in XHTML 1.1.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use "noscript" in an XHTML/XML document because it disables the parser for the "noscript" content and you can't do that in XML. The parser cannot be temporarily disabled or turned off.

For example, CSE HTML Validator generates this message for XHTML documents:
*XHTML documents must not use the "noscript" element. This is because the way "noscript" works by "turning off" the parser when scripts are enabled, which can't be done in XML. Also, the "noscript" element is explicity not allowed in HTML5 for this reason.*

If you want to use "noscript" properly, then you'll need to change the document type to HTML5 (recommended) or HTML4 instead of XHTML.

Comment: How does your last recommendation cohere with the ending of your quote, "Also, the "noscript" element is explicity not allowed in HTML5 for this reason."?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [official validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to validate your HTML.  The following code validated perfectly fine for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>I AM YOUR DOCUMENT TITLE REPLACE ME</title>
  </head>
  <body>    
    <div id="head">
      <noscript>
        <p>JavaScript is disabled.</p>
      </noscript>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**  Interestingly, the W3C validator claims that the parser is based on the validator at the link you provided.

> *'The uploaded document was successfully checked as HTML5. This means that the resource in question identified itself as "HTML5" and that we successfully performed a formal validation of it. The parser implementations we used for this check are based on validator.nu (HTML5).'*

Perhaps the validator at http://validator.nu is an older version.  **Edit edit:** Nope, it validates just fine there too.  Checked as HTML5 and XHTML 1.0 Strict.

Comment: Use the HTML5 doctype. An error will be thrown: `XHTML element noscript not allowed as child of XHTML element div in this context.`

Comment: @Rob W: I did, there were no errors.  Let me try again. **edit** *'This document was successfully checked as HTML5!'*

Comment: Note, the poster states "XHTML".  It's possible they're not using HTML5 as the doctype and there's a more strict syntax in XHTML 1/1.1 than HTML5?

Comment: @AndyE I have tested and confirmed the OPs error. However, I am also able to parse your test case as valid.